# Meaning of x:Key, x:Name, x:Type, x:Static in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

On the msdn site there is big article: [XAML overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx#xaml_root_elements_and_xaml_namespaces)

And there is the part describing what is: `x:Key, x:Class, x:Name` etc. but the problem is that all that said there about it is very abstractional with no examples.

I know that when I create an element in xaml and set: `x:Name = "abc"` then in the cs file I have access to this object by `abc.fieldORmethod()` but what about the rest. **Could anybody provide explanation with examples for that statements below?**

> - **`x:Key`**: Sets a unique key for each resource in a `ResourceDictionary`    (or similar dictionary concepts in other
>     frameworks). x:Key will    probably account for 90% of the x: usages
>     you will see in a typical    WPF application's markup. `x:Class`:
>     Specifies the CLR namespace and    class name for the class that
>     provides code-behind for a XAML page.    You must have such a class to
>     support code-behind per the WPF    programming model, and therefore
>     you almost always see x: mapped,    even if there are no resources.
> - **`x:Name`**: Specifies a run-time object name for the instance that exists    in run-time code after an object element is processed.
>     In general,    you will frequently use a WPF-defined equivalent
>     property for x:Name.    Such properties map specifically to a CLR
>     backing property and are    thus more convenient for application
>     programming, where you    frequently use run time code to find the
>     named elements from    initialized XAML. The most common such property
>     is    `FrameworkElement.Name`. You might still use x:Name when the
>     equivalent    WPF framework-level Name property is not supported in a
>     particular    type. This occurs in certain animation scenarios.
> - **`x:Static`**: Enables a reference that returns a static value that is not    otherwise a XAML-compatible property.
> - **`x:Type`**: Constructs a Type reference based on a type name. This is    used to specify attributes that take Type, such as
>     `Style.TargetType`,    although frequently the property has native
>     string-to-Type conversion    in such a way that the x:Type markup
>     extension usage is optional.

Comment: Did you try the pages here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753327(v=vs.110).aspx
It seems to have some better examples

Comment: @Yoda I have the same problem and thanks for posting and upvote from me. Your question is perfectly clear and the problem is very real

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**x:Key** is used in case you want to define some resource which can be reused in your xaml. It is equivalent to Key of normal dictionary.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

**x:Static** is used to donate some static data. Suppose you want to declare brush with some static color defined under SystemColors enum.

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlColor}" />
```

**x:Type** is equivalent to `Type` class in C#. It denotes type of class.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"/>
```

**x:Name** is used to provide name to control so that it can be accessed from code behind using that name or can be binded within XAML using ElementName.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt1" Text="Test"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="txt2" Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=txt}"/>
```

Comment: 1. `x:Key` can be used to put an item into **any** `IDictionary`, not just `ResourceDictionary`. 2. I'd say that `x:Type` is similar to `typeof` and **returns** `Type`. 3. `x:Name` can be referenced with `x:Reference` too (`Binding` is specific to WPF).

Comment: @Athari - True +1. There are multiple uses, i just posted one relevant sample of usage.

Comment: what about `x:Class`?